# Integrating the Banners service of Playscape SDK for Unity, Android

Tags: android, playscape

Using the (latest) playscape SDK for Android devices and Unity, we have not successfully managed to get Banners showing up.
It is apparent, when testing on the phone, that the banners 'hitboxes' are there, as I can click the banners (which usually takes me to the google play store for a game), but the banners are not visible. I am using the functions described in the Playscape SDK documentation to render them. The video and interstitials show up fine and work as expected.
Looking through the scene view, I have verified that the banners do not seem to be hiding behind NGUI. 
When testing in the PC environment, I see debug outputs verifying 'mock banners' were called.
How can I test the Banner functionality for errors?
I am using the Playscape SDK 1.6.

Comment: Which playscape SDK version do you have? you can check it in playscapeconfig.xml under assets\playscape (playscape_publishing_kit_version)

Comment: I am using the Playscape SDK 1.6 - according to files in Unity.
The SDK documentation was generated Fri Jul 17 2015

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest SDK (1.13) and update if this still happens. The SDK contains important update to Vungle package that has a security issue. you can download it from here: https://dashboard.playscape.com/o/download/PlayscapePublishingKit-unity.zip

Comment: This is supposedly the latest SDK, we did the update and the integration to get rid of the Vungle security issue - the old SDK had banners working fine. I have been provided help from Artem, Synergetica to integrate it and during that process we had plenty of situations where we verified the version of the SDK.
1.6 is the versioning provided by files in the Unity Package. The SDK documentation was generated  Fri Jul 17 2015.